# How to add variable to xhr.open outta Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, which should on loading of every new domain in browser get special remote url, add to it the current domain (like with `window.location.hostname`), get special metric from the target page, produced on this way, (with `XMLHttpRequest` and `XPath`),  and show this metric as `BadgeText`.

I've got nearly all working, but only with static url. If instead of `"+window.location.hostname+"` i hardcode any domain name,  everything works like expected - i get the number as `BadgeText`. But how can i get this work with domain currently loaded in browser?

This is my `background.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabid, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'currentWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
        let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
        currentDomain = newUrl.hostname;
        console.log(currentDomain);
    });
});

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "url part 1" + window.location.hostname + "url part 2", true);

xhr.responseType = 'document';

xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log("XHR callback readyState = " + this.readyState);
    if (this.readyState == 4) {

        function getElementByXpath(path) {
            return xhr.response.evaluate(path, xhr.response, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
        }

        console.log(getElementByXpath("//div[@class='data-mini']/span/span[@class='value']/text()"));

        var badgeText = getElementByXpath("//div[@class='data-mini']/span/span[@class='value']/text()");
        console.log(badgeText);
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: String(badgeText) });

        console.log(String(badgeText));
    }
}
```

With the first part i get clean domain of the currently loaded tab into console. The second part should do the rest job.

**What remains**, is to get

`currentDomain`

into

`xhr.open("GET", "https://app.sistrix.com/app_visindex/__loadModule/lang/de/domain/"+currentDomain+"/source/de/ref/app_controller_efcdc3b3cab713326d8830ac95b499e454ae4e46053a5cc6/_action/_result/_cache//_loadbox/empty/_ajax/1/_module-expire/217287/_controller", true);`

The main goal:

- on visiting of every other domain the url in `xhr.open` is modified with the current domain,
- `XHRHttpRequest` gets new number from HTML element defined with `XPath`,
- the number is shown as `BadgeText`.

Comment: The background script runs in a separate background page with its own chrome-extension:// URL so using `location` won't help. Look for examples of using chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted (requires "webNavigation" in "permissions") or chrome.tabs.onUpdated (requires "tabs" in "permissions" to get the URL). Also, you'll need to specify the updated tab id as `tabId`, see the documentation for setBadgeText.

Comment: Hmm, i've managed it to get the current url into alert, with `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   alert(changeInfo.url);
});` from `background.js`. What is the way to transfer its domain into the url i query with `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: if (changeInfo.url) doRequest(new URL(changeInfo.url).hostname)

Comment: Afraid to have no clue, how to use this line. Tried some variants, which were obvious for me, but no luck. Don't even got to work `console.log (changeInfo.url);`.

Comment: @wOxxOm WOWOWOW! I'm near! Got the current clean domain into console! Look at this!

Comment: by visiting domains, you mean just to switch tabs or it can reload a specific page ?

Comment: @Evgeniy have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you want to get page information + it's current hostname when switching tabs.

So { `pageInfo`, `currentHost` }.

This information you want to pass to the background and do an XHR with the right host...

Here is how would I solve this:

In your `content.js`:

```
// Gets needed data from the content when the tab changes (i.e on window focus).
// For example I will take the content of first paragraph and the hostname:

window.onfocus = function () {
  const firstParagraphText = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
  const hostName = window.location.host;

  this.sendDataToBackground({ paragraph: firstParagraphText, host: hostName });
}


function sendDataToBackground(data) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, data);
}
```

Then in your `background.js` you have to retrieve the info sent by content:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  console.log('First paragraph = ', request.paragraph);
  console.log('Host = ', request.host);

  // DO XHR WITH NEW HOST...
});
```

This works for me, if you wish I can create a public repo with one working example...

Answer (score 0):

The correct and working code is:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active' : true, 'currentWindow': true}, function(tabs){
        let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
        var currentDomain = newUrl.hostname;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "url part 1"+currentDomain+"url part 2", true);
        xhr.responseType='document';
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4) {

        function getElementByXpath(path) {
          return xhr.response.evaluate(path, xhr.response, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
        }
            var badgeText = getElementByXpath("//div[@class='data-mini']/span/span[@class='value']/text()");
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(badgeText)});
          chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: '#1d2554' });
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: With my approach you don't need any permissions :)